# Adding a function() to .zshrc

Tags: zshrc

I would like to create a shortcut for rebasing x number of commits:- `git rebase -i HEAD~3`.  I have a function `function gri() { git rebase --interactive HEAD~"$1"; }` and have tried adding it to my .zshrc file, .bashrc & .bash_profile.  But where ever I add it when I try and run `gri(2)` for example, I get the error `zsh: command not found: gri(2)`

**SOLVED**

Just needed to remove `function`, `gri() { git rebase --interactive HEAD~"$1"; }` works a treat :D

Comment: Not really up to speed on shell functions, but shouldn't it be invoked like `gri 2`?

Comment: hmmm invoking with `gri 2` gave this error `fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream 2`

Comment: (and I have 4 commits on the branch mentioned above)

Comment: Please add your solution as an actual answer and accept it!